# Trying to make a user follow another user using SoundCloud JavaScript API

Tags: soundcloud

This is the first time I am using SoundCloud API and I am trying to make a user follow another user using SoundCloud JavaScript SDK.

Please refer to the documentation link :- https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow

- For Python and Ruby, they are using access_token (received after authentication call) for this call which seems to be correct.
- With JavaScript, I have received access_token on the callback URL once the user is logged in from the popup.
- But in the document, for the JavaScript they have sent callback_url and client_id again. It does not seem correct.

However, I have tried sending client_id, callback_url, access_token variables in different combinations but it is still not giving any response.

Basically, I have authenticated the user from the popup dialog and in the callback URL I want to make this user follow some another user.

Here is the Popup code:-

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script>

        SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/test/callback.php'
        });

        // initiate auth popup
        SC.connect().then(function() {
          return SC.get('/me');
        });
</script>
```

..and the Callback URL code:-

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script>
        SC.initialize({
          access_token: 'received_by_get_method_on_callback_url'        
        });

        SC.connect().then(function() {
            // Follow user with ID 3207
            SC.put('/me/followers/3207').then(function(){
              // Unfollow the same user
              //SC.delete('/me/followers/3207');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the part of code where you prepare and send your request to the server.

Comment: Hi @technico I have edited the post and added the code.